# How to remove notification action

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a method that creates/updates a notification:

```
private void createNotification(Boolean removeAction) {
        getButtonPendingIntent().cancel();

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My App")
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);

        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        bigTextStyle.setBigContentTitle("My App");

        if (removeAction) {
            String msg = "Some message";
            bigTextStyle.bigText(msg);
            builder.setContentText(msg);
            // this will remove button but leaves an empty space where the button existed
            builder.addAction(0, null, null);
        } else {
            String msg = "You are logged in. Slide down to logout.";
            bigTextStyle.bigText(msg);
            builder.setContentText(msg);
            builder.addAction(R.drawable.some_icon, "My Button", getButtonPendingIntent());
        }

        builder.setStyle(bigTextStyle);

        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());
    }
```

Sometimes I need to remove the action that I created with the notification.  If I just create a new build and notify of a new event that does not have the action, the action button still remains.

I add in this code:

```
builder.addAction(0, null, null);
```

And that removes the action button, however still leaves a blank space in the notification screen where the button used to be.  Is there a 'right' way to remove an action from a notification, and the space it used?

Answer (score 2):

A lot of time has spent from last answer. But I think for someone it could be useful. In  `NotificationCompat.Builder` there is an ArrayList - `mActions`. I cleared this Arraylist via calling `myNotificationBuilder.mActions.clear()`. And it helped me to remove the action button from my notification without recreating it.

Comment: When you update to gradle plugin version 3.3.0 it will complain about the statement above : `Error: Builder.mActions can only be accessed from within the same library group (groupId=androidx.core) [RestrictedApi]`

Comment: @toobsco42 I ignore that, because I must as there is no alternative to it and creating a new NotificationCompat may cause visual glitches (popping/flashing of the notification, etc). I was updating icons and those stopped as well, so I am clearing actions and adding them again with new icons. Ugly but no alternatives as far as I know, yet.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently. The only solution I could think of was to cancel the previous notification first right before I updated it.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancel(100);
notificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (removeAction) {
            String msg = "Some message";
            bigTextStyle.bigText(msg);
            builder.setContentText(msg);
            // this will remove button but leaves an empty space where the button existed
            if(!builder.mActions.isEmpty()) builder.mActions.clear();// remove button (:
        } else {
            String msg = "You are logged in. Slide down to logout.";
            bigTextStyle.bigText(msg);
            builder.setContentText(msg);
            builder.addAction(R.drawable.some_icon, "My Button", getButtonPendingIntent());
        }
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Eugen, in my Notification class I build this method:

```
/**
 * Cancel the notification by its id
 * @param contexto
 * @param id
 */
public static void cancell(Context contexto, int id){
    NotificationManager notificacaoManager = (NotificationManager) contexto.getSystemService(Activity.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificacaoManager.cancel(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having the error "Builder.mActions can only be accessed from within the same library group (groupId=androidx.core)" I solved as follows:

1. First cancel your previous notification

   notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
2. create a new notification builder without adding the action buttons

> java

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder2 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID);
                builder2.setContentTitle("Same title as before").setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder2.build());
```

Answer (score -1):

I think if you add `.setAutoCancel(true)` to your builder maybe do the job

Answer (score -1):

Just clear the actions from notifications and notify it.

```
notificationBuilder.mActions.clear();
notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
```